# Is it possible to have ajax call a php script every microseconds to check if a textfile has changed?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, fopen

I'm in the process of creating a lapcounter for a slot car racetrack.
Whenever a car passes a sensor, it sends some data through a microcontroller to the computer which writes the data to a file. Now I would like to detect whenever that file has changed, meaning that a car has passed the sensor, and store that data onto a database (mysql), then present it on the screen in real time. The filecheck would have to be done continuously, and as rapidly as possible..

Also a timer that counts in hundreds of a seconds would be nice to present.. But that's another thing, and has nothing to do with this question...

There may be better ways of doing this, but I'm pretty sure it could be possible with some ajax, php and mysql on a local server that is directly connected to the microcontroller.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but Facebook, Stackoverflow, and instant messages/chats uses some similar future I would assume..

Comment: You can run a function periodically with `setInterval`, but the timer granularity is milliseconds, not microseconds.

Comment: And you have to consider that he amount of data returned/internet speed and other factors can also affect the client accessing it.

Comment: I doubt that FB and SO are really checking for changes every microsecond. It's probably more like every 5 or 10 seconds.

Comment: how about node.js to push instead of pull? (event trigger)

Comment: in your case i think Web Sockets will respond better than ajax . try this . http://socketo.me/

Comment: websocket is what SO uses for most of their things including the chat.

Comment: It would be more efficient to use long polling method. if you have decided to go with jquery ajax

Comment: Yes. Every miliseconds is probably more like it ;) and that's fast enought.. even a second delay is ok too. But this looks promising :) I'm familiar with jquery ajax, so if that's possible, I think I'll try with that first.. But I'll also have a look into websockets though.

Answer (score 1):

The Logic for file Change can be on php end 'check_the_file_change.php'

The below is the smaple JS code, which will send the request every 1 second to a php file

'check_the_file_change.php'

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    function checkFileChange(){ 

          setTimeout(function () {

                                   $.ajax({
                                     url    :'check_the_file_change.php',
                                     type   : 'POST',
                                     data   :{
                                      user_secret : 'XXXX' 
                                     },
                                     success : function(respsone){

                                           if(response == "true"){                           
                                               //file changed
                                           }else{          
                                              //file not chnaged   
                                           }

                                     },
                                     complete : function(){
                                        checkFileChange(); //net file check after 1 sec from the completion of the previous request
                                     }                                   
                                   });



                    },1000);
          }

    }

});
```

ON PHP end

```
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); // use this in case the ajax call is coming from other domain 


 $filename = 'somefile.txt';

  if (file_exists($filename)) {

        if( time() - filemtime($filename) > 60){ 

          echo "false";

        }else{ //file is modified 1 minute ago

          echo "true";

        }

  }
```

Comment: A check every 1 second is fast enought. A second delay is not noticable since the monitor is not the focusarea when racing. 
Since each lap lasts for like, 10-15/20 seconds (depending on the length of the track), I should probably change the `filetime()` to a lower value? How about `1`? as in "since last check"? Or am I missunderstanding the code?

Comment: The time of checking the request  is set in jQuery Ajax Call (currently 1000ms) , so you can make that to (15000ms - 20000ms). On the PHP end `filetime()` will get the last modified timestamp of the file

Comment: I understand. I have to check at least every second since there are two cars that runs through the sensor, meaning that the file can be updated at any random time... So I need to check for fresh data as rapidly as possible - as i mentioned in the question..